# How to adjust height of angular datatable based on data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am facing an issue in adjusting the height of the datatable when the webservice is called to populate the same.

I have a page that contains a collapsible `div` and a `datatable`. When the I collapse the div, I calculate the height and resize the table using inline CSS.
However, whenever I call the webservice to populate the data, the data table again shrinks back to a smaller size (the size it has in expanded state).

I want to know how to adjust the height of the datatable dynamically. I cant share much of the code here due to certain client constraints.

Here is how I assign the height

```
tableHght.css({ 'height': yLength + 'px', 'overflow': 'auto', 'width': '100%' });`
```

Comment: Probably the table will be re-initialized if you reload data from the web service and looses the style information. But wihout a working code snippet from you it's impossible to help.

Comment: hi yes i know it will be difficult..But i will try and create a dummy example soon since I can't share the complete code over here...Yes your right when you say the table gets re-initialized but my doubt is how to calculate the height of the re-initialized table at runtime and apply the same to the datatable...is there any property or option for the same

Answer (score 3):

YOu can do so by using ng-class directive as follows:-

```
<div class="yourTable" ng-style="{ 'height': yourModelToProvideValue }">
```

in the controller

```
$scope.yourModelToProvideValue = "200px" ;
```

or simply

```
<div class="yourTable" ng-style="yourModelToProvideValue">
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.yourModelToProvideValue = "height : 200px" ;
```

Comment: hi @bose_geek: thanks for the response. is it possible to set the calculated height in this way? I mean dynamically rather than hardcoding the value

Comment: Shouldn't you use `ng-style` instead of `ng-class`?

Comment: @ParthDoshi - Yes, you can calculate the height based on some logic and then you can set the same way as above.

Comment: @Bose_geek: I tried your solution but datatables actually creates a wrapper around the table whose height is calculated by the library at runtime. So in that case no matter what value we provide for height..it always takes the datatable generated height value

Comment: @Bose_geek: can u add me on gmail - my id --> androidparth@gmail.com